# onCreate(Bundle) in fragment error when i copy content from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

**Hi,Im trying to copy code from Activity to Fragment but it gives me error when i try to compile "cannot override onCreate(Bundle)". Here is my Activity code**:

```
package com.candyshop.www.candyshop;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    private List<MyData> data_list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab1);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        data_list  = new ArrayList<>();
        load_data_from_server(0);

        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,data_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if(gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == data_list.size()-1){
                    load_data_from_server(data_list.get(data_list.size()-1).getId());
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void load_data_from_server(int id) {

            AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder()
                            .url("http://192.168.178.26/test/script.php?id="+integers[0])
                            .build();
                    try {
                        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                        for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                            MyData data = new MyData(object.getInt("id"),object.getString("description"),
                                    object.getString("image"));

                            data_list.add(data);
                        }



                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        System.out.println("End of content");
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };

        task.execute(id);
    }


}
```

**And the code from my Fragment is**

```
package com.candyshop.www.candyshop;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by Reinhard Bonnke on 5/14/2017.
 */

public class females extends Fragment {
    public females() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    }


}
```

**Can you please help me know how i can avoid this error or how i can copy the code to the fragment**

Comment: Copy the code from Activity.onCreate to Fragment.onCreateView.

Comment: Hi, im trying that but im getting more errors, where exactly should i start copying from

Answer (score 0):

This may help :https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Try this in your fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        data_list  = new ArrayList<>();
        load_data_from_server(0);
        //  more UI from your activity ....
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot this worked, Thanks. One more error, it underlines the (this,2)  and (this,data_list) and brings error:" incompatible types; females cannot be converted to Context"

Comment: Hi, `GridLayoutManager` needs a Context, you can try this `new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2)` .  So does the `Adapter`

Comment: Hi, i found out the problem instead of using (this,2); i replaced it with (getActivity(),2); Its now perfect. Thanks sooo much for your help